# How to use node's coordinates in AODV packets in NS-2?

Tags: ns2

I need to add a new field(`location [x,y]`) to **Hello packets**  in AODV. I define nodes location by random function in TCL. now I want to use their location in C++. what should I do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Simply you need to add your custom fields in packet header structure of ns-2 and use it in your code.

See the following link for more information :

http://www.projectguideline.com/topic/how-to-use-nodes-coordinates-in-aodv-packets-in-ns-2